# Show hidden div to select a Radio button jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, toggle

: 
I want to show a div when the user select the correct choice of a radio button. By default the option to not have to show the div is selected. I would like the right choice when unmarked went back to hide the div. Here's the code.

Form:

```
<input class="radio" id="re" type="radio" name="recogida" value="domicilio">
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="recogida" value="local" checked><br />
            <div id="domicilio" class="oculto">
            <hr />
            <h3>¿Necesitas cambio?:</h3>
            <input type="number" name="cambio" min="1" max="500" />
            </div>

<style>
 .oculto{
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

Jquery Script option 1:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='recogida']").click(function() {
        var nom = $(this).val();
        $("#"+nom).show();
    }); 
});
```

Jquery Script option 2:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $(".radio").click(function () {    
            $('#domicilio').toggle(2000);
             });
    });
```

What's the solution? Thanks!!

Comment: your code is working here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CBjG/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/btE53/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#domicilio').hide();
    $(".radio").change(function () { //use change event
        if (this.value == "domicilio") { //check value if it is domicilio
            $('#domicilio').stop(true,true).show(2000); //than show
        } else {
            $('#domicilio').stop(true,true).hide(2000); //else hide
        }
    });
});
```